# What is the coolant fluid used in a 2015 BMW X 5–5.0i turbo coolant reservoir?

Tags: coolant, bmw

What is the coolant fluid used in a 2015 BMWX 5–5.0i turbo coolant reservoir?

Comment: FYI there is no such thing as "turbo coolant". The car is a turbo, and needs coolant

Answer (score 1):

BMW original anti-freeze concentrated fluid, part number is 83 19 2 211 914.

Must be diluted with clean water(probably distilled) in proportion 1:1